# Jpa Enum how to map to column value with space in it?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, enums

I am following below enum tutorial in JPA configuration. My JPA is connected to mysql DB. However some values in the enum column contains space inside it. So I created a Java enum type with a String field to store these column values.

The question is, How to map this complex enum type using JPA `@Enumerated(Enum.TYPE = String)` annotation? It seems not working.

[The Enum example I followed.](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/jpa-enumerated/)

The Enum type for my case:

```
public enum Complex {

    VALUE1('value one'),
    VALUE2('value two'),

    private final String name;

    private Complex(String name) {
        this.name = name;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

To Hibernate there is no such thing as `name` property in your enum so this won't work like that. You will need custom serializer/deserializer. How Hibernate would know that it is supposed to use `name` and not string form of enum like `VALUE1` and vice versa?

```
@Converter
public class ComplexConverter implements AttributeConverter<Complex, String> {
 @Override
 public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Complex value){
     return value.name; //or whatever
 }

 @Override
 public Complex convertToEntityAttribute(String value) {
   ///// map string to Complex enum somehow
 }

}
```

And in your entity

```
   @Column
   @Convert(converter = ComplexConverter.class)
   private Complex complex;
```

Not tested but should work and show you the way how to do this.

Comment: This is good to start with. However my converter got ignored. After googling i saw similar occurrences. But I am still investigating on it.

Comment: You can try to add converter class to persistence.xml however this doesnt make much sense as you pass `Class` instance in annotation so no declaration should berequired. In general it should work - I have done something like that in the past.

Comment: @user8328365 also you must remove `Enumerated` from converted column

Answer (score 0):

You can post the error ? But using `@Enumerated(Enum.TYPE = String)` the JPA will persist VALUE1 or VALUE2 and field in table should support the data type.